# React: Newbie: OAP : process child button click call parent function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I come from the world of VB and other archaic languages and am trying to learn React/Javascript and have a simple problem - which I don't know how to solve, but I feel should be very simple.

I have a functional component which renders a dropdown and a button, when the dropdown changes I am using usestate to keep track of the select item.

I then have another functional component which 'hosts' this component - I guess the correct terminology is a parent.
what I want to do is when the button is clicked I retrieve the dropdown item(which I have stored) and pass the value to a function in the 'host' component,which then does other stuff

but I cant for the life of me figure out how to do this :-(

Comment: There are 2 ways you can go about doing this. Either define the state within the parent, and pass the setter to the child component, or use something like Redux or ContextAPI to store the currently selected item in a global state.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this properly you need to get data from the child component to the parent one.

You first of need to define the state in the parent component and then pass it down to the child component like so

```
const ChildComponents = ({state,setState}) => { // accepts the state and setState from the parent component
  return(
    <select onChange={(e) => setState(e.currentTarget.value)} value={state}>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  )
}

const ParentComponent = () =>{
  const [state,setState] = useState();

  return <ChildComponents state={state} setState={setState} />
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct. I have a dropdown component., which is basically hard coded with the options as they are always static. there is also a button, which I want to trigger a function in the hosting function (not the function that the component is created in). As part of the function I want it to accept a value of the selected dropdown.  so something like  cmdButton onClick={myfunction(selected option}